# Error using \usepackage{subcaption} in LaTeX document

Tags: subcaption

Right now, I am writing my bachelor thesis and using LaTeX for the first time, using the template made available at https://www.overleaf.com/read/jtsdtwkcjcyq .

I am writing the results as I am writing this message. To make a nice presentation of my results, I would like to dedicate a page to a subfigure with 3 rows and 2 columns of figures. I want to have this in my thesis:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I try to place this in my thesis, it gives an error when I try to use \usepackage{subcaption}. The error is (There were 2 error messages)
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty:73:
Undefined co
ntrol sequence.
l.73 \caption@SetupOptions
                          {subcaption}{\captionsetup[sub]{#2}}%

The report.tex file looks as follows. (there are probably some usepackages that I don't need, but I am not yet familiar with all of latex and this is a standard template of my university).

I hope somebody knows this error and is able to help me :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{booksfsf}
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,fleqn]{booksfsf}
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{psfrag}   
\usepackage{cite}
\def\citepunct{], [}
\def\citedash{]--[}

\usepackage{pdfpages}                           % To allow inclusion of the frontpage as a pdf-page
\usepackage{caption}   
\usepackage{captspec}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\makeindex  
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwe}








\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[labelfont = it, font = footnotesize, hangindent = 26pt, parskip = 20pt]{subfig}


%change geometry of the lay-out
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry} % Marges

%change title properties
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize\itshape}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}                               % use helvetica for sans serif
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}               %    use sans serif by default


\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\includepdf{frontpage} % Include the frontpage which is a separate pdf. Make sure the pdf exists!
                       % Note: this only works with PDFlatex. If you use a different typesetter,
                       % then include the frontpage afterwards, e.g. using Adobe Acrobat

%\pagestyle{empty}


\newpage
\cleardoublepage

\include{preface}

\include{summary}


\tableofcontents

%\include{acronyms}

\mainmatter

\include{chap_introduction}

\include{theory}

\include{Experimental}

\include{Results}

%\include{chap_body}

%\include{chap_...}

%\include{chap_conclusions}

\cleardoublepage %to make sure that the first page number for the references is correctly listed in the TOC.
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEfull,Mybibliography}


\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\begin{appendix}

\include{appendix_A}

\end{appendix}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Is `booksfsf` and `captspec` available somewhere? Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that does not need external file which we don't have?

Comment: Hi Sam,

Thanks for your quick reply!
I am afraid i don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `graphics` if you load `graphicx`

Comment: Alright, thank you I will get rit of it right away

Comment: Coming back to your question, the template I am using is available on Overleaf under the name: University of Twente: Latex template for Telecommunication Engineering (TE) report.

Comment: Looking at `booksfsf.cls` after clicking on "open as template" on https://www.overleaf.com/read/jtsdtwkcjcyq , it looks like this document class defines its own `\@makecaption` etc, so it may not necessary work well with certainly packages e.g. `subcaption`

Comment: Hey LianTze Lim,

Thanks for your reply. Can you think of a way to circumvent or is there another way to produce the results in the same way i showed above in the figure?

Comment: If it defines its own captioning, you should also omit `caption`. Note that you are loading `hyperref` much, much too early. With a few specific exceptions, it should be loaded last. Which is the university template? The class? Or the preamble? Or both? If only the class, I suspect you should remove a chunk of preamble and go with their layout. Load `xcolor` rather than `color`. `subfig` works uneasily, at best, with `caption` and would not work properly with `subcaption` even setting aside whatever the class does.

Comment: Using `caption` and `captspec` together definitely does not make sense. Both packages re-define `\@makecaption` so you should decide which one to use. BTW: The error you get is because there is an outdated `caption.sty` and `caption3.sty` (from 2008) inside the document (template) folder. Just delete these files, so the files from TeXlive are used instead.

Answer (score 2):

If `\caption@SetupOptions` is an undefined command then the version of the `subcaption` is not compatible to the version of the `caption` package. (There should be a warning about this in the log file.)

Since `caption` and `subcaption` are always released in a bundle it seems that you have an old version as local copy (from 2008 or older) of `caption.sty` and/or `caption3.sty` in your document folder. So deleting these files should help.

BTW: Using `caption` and `captspec` together definitely does not make sense. Both packages re-define `\@makecaption` so you should decide which one to use (and drop the usage of the other).